# RSpec - can't write unknown attribute (enum)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

The model User:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  enum my_enum: [
    :some_value1,
    #....
  ]
```

Also I have a migration which adds `my_enum` to User:

```
def change
  add_column :users, :my_enum, :integer
end
```

And the fixture for FactoryGirl:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    email { Faker::Internet.email }
    password { Faker::Internet.password(10) }
    password_confirmation { password }
    my_enum { nil }
  end 
end
```

Everything works fine.  But when I run a test, I get an error:

```
Failure/Error: paid_user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
     ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError:
       can't write unknown attribute `my_enum`
```

Comment: Is the column available while you are using in your Rails console?

Comment: @ArupRakshit, shouldn't I reload a schema for the tests somehow?

Comment: Did you run `rake db:test:prepare`?  Depending on which version of Rails you are using, this might not be necessary, but if you think the test schema is not up to date, maybe that's the issue.

Comment: I meant to test in Rails console in Test environment. :-)

Comment: @mrrogers, the tags say what version of Rails I'm using.

Comment: I was faced with this issue, and I solved it by running: ` bin/rails db:schema:load RAILS_ENV=test` It worked for me because the code was working in my dev env but not in my test env.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like your test database has not been migrated properly. 
Try running the following command:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
```

.. and then try to run rspec again.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem to OP and this did not solve it for me :-/

Comment: I am having the same problem, rspec is not letting me do a failing test for a bad enum type.  It works fine for nil though.